# Linq GroupBy and Aggregate

Tags: linq, group-by, aggregate

Given the following list:

```
var data = new[]
    {
        new {category = "Product", text = "aaaa"},
        new {category = "Product", text = "bbbb"},
        new {category = "Product", text = "bbbb"},
    };
```

how do I group it by category and return an object with category and a description of the different text put together ??

ie. would like to end yp with:

```
{
    categroy="Product"
    description = "aaaa,bbbb,cccc"
}
```

tried the following GroupBy and Aggregate, but something is not right

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.category).Select(g => new
    {
        category = g.Key,
        description = g.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + "," + s2)
     });
```

TIA

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why don't you use `String.Join(IEnumerable)` method?

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.category).Select(g => new
{
    category = g.Key,
    description = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.text))
});
```

With `Aggregate` you should do following:

```
    description = g.Aggregate(string.Empty, (x, i) => x + "," + i.text)
```

First parameter sets seed start value to `String.Empty`. Second parameter defines method to concatenate current seed value (`string`) with current element (`anonymous_type`).

Answer (score 9):

```
data.GroupBy(x => x.category).Select(g => new
    {
        category = g.Key,
        description = g.Select(x => x.text).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + "," + s2)
     });
```

Comment: How does this improve the accepted answer? Also, just giving a code snippet as answer isn't very helpful. A little explanation why this is a good solution helps OP and future readers.

Comment: You 'r write, this answer doesn't have significant improve, but it' s a simple answer for original question (just add missing Select method), while all other answers change solution and give a correct but maybe complicated answer.

Comment: What "all other answers"? The only other answer isn't complicated at all.